# Emulate clock with second channel of system timer?

Tags: timer, x86

Is it possible to emulate clocks (with seconds, minutes, hours) using second channel of system timer? On x86 architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about the 8253/8254 timer, you could try, but only the first timer (out of the 3 of the 8253/8254 chip) generates interrupts. And then, you shouldn't probably touch the one that may be involved in memory regeneration and the last one would need to be used for that purpose only an not for the speaker.